How to determine compatible Node version range?
I have just installed a new version of node (20.11.0) and npm (10.2.4)
I have taken an old project and updated all the packages.
I have updated .npmrc by adding engine-strict=true
and added the node and npm versions to my package.json
"engines": {
  "npm": "10.2.4",
  "node": "20.11.0"
},

Should I be specifying the exact node and npm version that I am using?
If No, how to determine the version range? eg
"engines" : { 
  "npm" : ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0",
  "node" : ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0"
}


According to the official documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#engines you are doing it right.
